# Keep batch script running after launching powershell within

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, sequential

I am using a batch script to automate a lot of tasks I have to run on a computer.
In the batch file I have a menu making you choose between each task separately or do everything.
When I choose to do everything, after launching the first .ps1 it just kills my cmd window.

I found some way to keep the window open but the script doesn't continue...
Also I created a "master file" to call all the ".ps1" and tried those cmds: call, /wait
The call feature works and they all start. So I don't understand why they would do the same in my script.
The cmd lines bellow are not bellow each other in my script because I want to be able to call them separately.

Part of the script I would like to run properly:

```
echo Windows Layout
start /wait PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dp0Customisation\Export_Import_Layout.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"

echo Remove Unwanted Apps
start /wait PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dp0Clean\RemoveAppx.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
wmic product where name="WinZip 22.5" call uninstall
ping -n 6 localhost >nul
Taskkill /IM /F "MicrosoftEdge.exe"
Taskkill /IM /F "MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe"
Taskkill /IM /F "MicrosoftEdgeSH.exe"
%~dp0Clean\MCPR.exe
```

The master.bat looks like this :

```
call PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dp0InstallChocoAndApps.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
call PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dp0Clean\RemoveAppx.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Any hint would be appriciated.
Please keep in mind I am not a script specialist.

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Managed to solve my issue by adding start "" /wait instead of start /wait

Comment: If your issue is solved, please take down the question.

Comment: Alternatively, you can post it as an answer and mark it Accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my issue by adding start "" /wait instead of start /wait